# Film identification : Possesion of cursed document leads to death (by giant gargoyle)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify an old classic (black and white) film from the UK.

The main plot consisted of a cursed document and the film featured a dramatic ending with giant gargoyle and train wreck.

Comment: Roughly when did you see it? Do you have any memories of actors or characters? Was it a TV movie? Did you see it in theaters or on TV?

Comment: Rough (timeframe) seen on TV in the early 80s, but believe its much older than that. possibly from the 50s

Comment: Sounds like a Lovecraft (or Cthulhu mythos, even if by another author) story, off the top of my head.  Might be an adaptation..

Comment: @KHW This doesn't particularly sound Lovecraftian at all. Moreso a list of all film adaptations of Lovecraft's stories can [easily be found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_based_on_works_by_H._P._Lovecraft) and nothing fitting this description is listed.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore -  *shrug*  It's not that uncommon for Lovecraft.  Forbidden knowledge/items/etc, and beings coming after you.  See [The Hound](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/h.aspx), The Hounds of Tindalos, [The Statement of Randolf Carter](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/src.aspx), etc.  Learn / see (or be seen by) / get the wrong thing, and evil comes after you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be "[*Night of the Demon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Demon)" (1957) movie, loosely based on M. R. James's "*Casting the Runes*" book.

Comment: I believe you are right. Sounds familiar. Need to see if there is any footage on utube.

Comment: Try this:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcPcJ9ycEu4  The newer film 'Drag me to Hell' takes inspiration from it too.

Answer (score 2):

I also think it's Night of the Demon (US title "Curse of the Demon").  At film's end, the cursed hero tricks the evil Julian Karswell into accepting the rune scroll. The scroll blows out of the train and along the track, with Karswell running after it, hoping to cancel the curse. But the scroll spontaneously combusts, and Karswell is doomed. The giant demon appears and claws him to shreds. When the police find him, they think a passing train ran over him. When the hero starts toward the police group, his girlfriend stops him, saying "It's better not to know."  He thinks then says "Maybe it is better not to know."